# How make latest "latexrefman" available via texdoc?

Tags: texdoc

With all TeXLive 2016 packages updated on my Mac OS X (El Capitan) system, I find that commands

```
texdoc latex2e
```

and

```
texdoc latex2e-help-texinfo
```

both open the October 2015 version of `latex2e.pdf`. But there is a more recent version available at http://home.gna.org/latexrefman/, dated August 2016.

I want to make this more recent version available when I issue the command:

```
texdoc latexrefman
```

Here's what I've done so far:

1. Renamed the current, downloaded, `latex2e.pdf` to `latexrefman.pdf` and put it in my local texmf tree, in `/Users/me/Library/texmf/doc/tex/latex`.
2. Created file `/Users/me/Library/texmf/texdoc/texdoc.cnf` with contents:

   ```
   alias latexrefman = /Users/me/Library/texmf/doc/tex/latex/latexrefman
   ```

What more do I need to do to get `texdoc latexrefman` to open this newer document version?

Here's some diagnostic information:

```
[me:~]$ texdoc --files
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/scripts/texdoc/texdoclib.tlu 0.85
Configuration files are:
    active  /Users/me/Library/texmf/texdoc/texdoc.cnf
    active  /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/texdoc/texdoc.cnf
Recommended file(s) for personal settings:
    /Users/me/Library/texmf/texdoc/texdoc.cnf

[me:~]$ kpsewhich --var-value TEXDOCS
{/Users/me/Library/texlive/2016/texmf-config,/Users/me/Library/texlive/2016/texmf-var,/Users/me/Library/texmf,!!/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-config,!!/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var,!!/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local,!!/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist}/doc//
```

Comment: Please don't add your solution as an edit to the question, but post it as an actual answer. Like this others will quickly see, that this question is answered.

Comment: Why not just put the new version of the pdf in your `TEXMFHOME` (findable via `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFHOME`). It is searched before `TEXMFLOCAL`, which is searched before `TEXMFDIST`....

Comment: As you'll see from my answer, I did place the pdf in my local texmf tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Rename the current, downloaded, `latex2e.pdf` to `latexrefman.pdf` and put it in the local texmf tree (on my system, `/Users/me/Library/texmf/doc/tex/latex`).
2. Created file `/Users/me/Library/texmf/texdoc/texdoc.cnf` with contents:

   ```
   alias latexrefman = /Users/me/Library/texmf/doc/tex/latex/latexrefman
   ```
3. Update the local `ls-R`:

   ```
   [me:~]$ mktexlsr ~/Library/texmf
   ```